# Nodejs is not available outside of its installation directory

Tags: node.js, installation, webserver

I installed nodejs 64bit on my windows8.

```
NOTE: By install, I mean I used node-v0.10.35-x64.msi andn its Windows8 for SurfacePro3.
I am not familiar with add PATH. What exactly should add I add and how I run it after I added it?
```

However, nodejs will not be available outside of its own installation folder.
For example,
if I installed it at /www/test directory, then it will not available either in www or any level after test, like, /www/test/anothertest. Only /www/test will have node running.

I test it by write node -v on /www/test directory in command prompt. I consider its available when it returns me the node version number. When it is not recognized, it will say `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command...'`

I insta

Comment: How are you "installing" it? You should use the official MSI installer for Windows.

Comment: Do you know about setting the path to include certain directories where you want the system to automatically look for executables like node when you type them at the command prompt?

Comment: Did you download the installer or the exec binary file?
In case you downloaded the binary file, it only will be available in the folder where it resides.
You have to either download the MSI installer or edit the PATH environment variable.

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you for letting me know :) Plz reply if any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer always fix everything....
Yes it did now everything works lol